# $\pi: X \to Y$ is a morphism of LRS, and $p \mapsto q$. If $g$ is a function vanishing at $q$, then it will pull back to a function vanishing at $p$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, definition, intuition

From Vakil's *Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*:

> 6.3.1. Definition. A locally ringed space is a ringed space $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ such that the stalks $\mathcal O_{X,p}$ are all local rings. A morphism of locally ringed spaces $\pi : X \to Y$ is a morphism of ringed spaces such that the induced map of stalks $π^\# : \mathcal O_{Y,q} \to \mathcal O_{X,p}$ sends the maximal ideal of the former into the maximal ideal of the latter (a “morphism of local rings”).

Next, Vakil writes

> This means something rather concrete and intuitive: “if $p \mapsto q$, and $g$ is a function vanishing at $q$, then it will pull back to a function vanishing at $p$.”

---

---

I was confused about this for a while. At first I was thinking that if $g$ is a function vanishing at $q$, then $\pi^\#_Y: \mathcal O_Y(Y) \to \mathcal O_X(X)$ satisfies $\pi^\# (g)(p)=g(\pi(p))=g(q)=0$. But Vakil does not define the map $\pi^\#$ between sections in this way.

*I came up with this next:*

Suppose $g$ is a function vanishing at $q \in Y$. Then $[g, Y] \in \mathcal O_{Y,q}$ is in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak m_q$. Since $π^\# : \mathcal O_{Y,q} \to \mathcal O_{X,p}$ satisfies $\pi^\#(\mathfrak m_q) \subset \mathfrak m_p$, then $[g,Y] \mapsto [\pi^\#_Y(g), X] \in \mathfrak m_p$. So, $\pi^\#(g)$ vanishes at $p$.

**Is this what is really going on?**

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "$g$ is a function vanishing at $q \in Y$."  Since, after all, the elements of $\mathcal O_Y(Y)$ are not necessarily functions on $Y$.

Comment: @D_S That's right. I keep forgetting the definition of vanishing at a point. I keep thinking that $g$ vanishing at $q$ means $g(q)=0$, which does not quite make sense as you mentioned. Vakil writes on page 138: *Functions on an open subset $U$ of a locally ringed space have values at each point of $U$. The value at $p$ of such a function lies in $\kappa(p)=\mathcal O_{X,p}/\mathfrak m_p$.*

Comment: Then the explanation you provided is correct

Answer (score 2):

**Question:** "This means something rather concrete and intuitive: “if p↦q, and g is a function vanishing at q, then it will pull back to a function vanishing at p.” Is this what is really going on?"

**Answer:** If $(f,f^{\#}): (X, \mathcal{O}_X) \rightarrow (Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ is a map of locally ringed spaces there is for any point $x\in X$ a well defined induced map at the stalks

$$f^{\#}_x: \mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$$

defined as follows: Given s germ $a:=(U,s)\in \mathcal{O}_Y(U)$ with $f(x)\in U$. It follows $a=0$ in the stalk at $f(x)$ iff there is an open set $f(x) \in V \subseteq U$ with $s_V=0$. The image of the element $(U,s)$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is the germ

$$f^{\#}_x((U,s)):= (f^{-1}(U), f^{\#}(U)(s)).$$

By definition (since it is a map of locally ringed spaces) it maps the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}$ to $\mathfrak{m}_{x}$. Hence if a section $s\in \mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}$ it follows

$$f^{\#}_x(s) \in \mathfrak{m}_x.$$

**Note:** You define the stalk at $x$ as follows: $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}:=lim_{x\in U}\mathcal{O}_X(U)$.